# azure files share with arm templates - possible?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Ok, I created Azure Files Share in Portal, it was quick and it works. But I need to add it into my ARM template. Is it possible to create Azure Files Share with ARM template? I couldn't find anything on it.

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the latest schema: [Microsoft.Storage.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/ac63429db6f68f325f5fc8d46fff9467d6dc30b6/schemas/2016-01-01/Microsoft.Storage.json) and it doesn't seem to allow any containers to be provisioned - just the account itself and its properties (redundancy options, hot/cool modes, etc).

I also tried exporting my template from the portal, and all it contained was the details I expected (given the schema definition above!) - ie. no container information.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it's still WIP

Comment: Russell is right, containers aren't supported by ARM templates at the moment.